What is the main purpose of TrustedWebActivityService in Android TWA?
I can't quite understand the main purpose of TrustedWebActivityService in Android TWA. The documentation says: At present it only serves requests to do with notifications.
I can't figure out what requests and what notifications. It receives NotificationManager, has different methods to work with notifications: notify, cancel, etc.
I have my own PWA (with Digital Asset Links) that implements WEB notifications. When the TWA app with this PWA is NOT INSTALLED, I receive notifications from this PWA from Chrome. When I install the TWA with this PWA, I can't receive notifications from either the TWA app or Chrome.
I thought TrustedWebActivityService is responsible for intercepting WEB Pushes from PWA and displaying them in a native way using Android notification API, because there are too many things that make it think that way (NotificationManager and methods inside). But it doesn't do anything.
Finally, my questions:

What is the main purpose of TrustedWebActivityService? Could you give some real-life examples?
Is it possible to somehow intercept WEB Pushes from PWA and display them natively? If yes, how to do it?
Why are there no notifications from my PWA from Chrome when the TWA app is installed?

